# cURL: How do I set the email subject when using -F (multipart / attachment)

Tags: curl, smtp

I'm trying to send an email using cURL. It has to include an attachment, so I'm using the -F / --form option:

(it's a single line, but I wrote here this way for clarificaiton)

```
curl smtp://smtp.example.com
     --ssl
     --mail-from sender@example.com
     --mail-rcpt receipt@example.com
     --user login
     -F "=<body.txt;encoder=quoted-printable"
     -F "=@files.zip;encoder=base64"
```

It kind of works; the mail arrives but I don't know how to set a header on the email itself (in fact, the only one I need by now is the Subject).

I've tried set it to the first part (the text):

```
     -F "=<body.txt;encoder=quoted-printable;headers=Subject: The files you requested"
```

But cURL effectively set the header to that part, resulting in an email like this (raw text):

```
     (email headers not including Subject)

     -----------------part-boundary
     Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
     Subject: The files you requested

     (content of body.txt)
     -----------------part-boundary
     Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="files.zip"
     Content-Type: application/octet-stream
     Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

     (content of files.zip encoded in base64)
     -----------------part-boundary--
```

So, how do I set the subject of the email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the documentation mentions HTTP only, the -H / --header option works for SMTP also.

So the way to set the email subject is to add this option to the command line:

```
-H "Subject: The files you requested"
```

But, as other headers (like To: and CC:) are needed, you may want to write them all to a file and use it:

```
-H @headers.txt
```

That's it.

Comment: Is there a chance you can post the actual solution and not just the part that's worked for you? This is incredibly rare to find.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you need. The actual solution is the command line in the question, plus the `-H` parameter and value in this answer.

Comment: I need you to copy the full working example to this answer instead of explaining how it can be found in 2 different places. This answer cannot be found anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: I think you want I answer your question about multipart/alternative, so I'm moving there.

Answer (score 1):

Fully worked example here. It breaks out all the elements of the curl command so you can see it working with all the components put together to create a message with an attachment, figure out the MIME type of the attachment and send it all without any interim files and using only native curl. [(GitHub - send-ses)](https://github.com/ambanmba/send-ses)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
    
sesAccess='AKIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
sesSecret='Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'   
sesFromName="Joe McJones"
sesFromAddress="joe.mcjones@fakeaddress.net"
sesToName="Mary McMary"
sesToAddress="mary.mcmary@notmyrealmail.com"
sesSubject="Test Email from Script"
sesSMTP="email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
sesPort="465"
sesMessage=$'Test of line 1\nTest of line 2'
sesFile="$1"
sesMIMEType=`file --mime-type "$sesFile" | sed 's/.*: //'`

curl -v --url smtps://$sesSMTP:$sesPort --ssl-reqd  --mail-from $sesFromAddress --mail-rcpt $sesToAddress  --user $sesAccess:$sesSecret -F '=(;type=multipart/mixed' -F "=$sesMessage;type=text/plain" -F "file=@$sesFile;type=$sesMIMEType;encoder=base64" -F '=)' -H "Subject: $sesSubject" -H "From: $sesFromName <$sesFromAddress>" -H "To: $sesToName <$sesToAddress>"
```

Comment: Please always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.